# An Error Occurred During Report Processing - Not Enough Memory Or Low Disk Space

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Working on Sql Report builder 3.0, all reports performed right but suddenly when I run the report an error window popup which shows the following error.

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details.
<br><br> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingCore' or one of its dependencies. There is not enough space on the disk. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070070)

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010Impl.CreateReportEditSession(String Report, String Parent, Byte[] Definition, String& EditSessionID, Warning[]& Warnings)

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.CreateReportEditSession(String Report, String Parent, Byte[] Definition, String& EditSessionID, Warning[]& Warnings)
```

Furthermore, I have given more 2 GB of free space to the log file and it will again surround all the remaining space. As I last viewed only 8.3 MB of free space remaining.

OS: Windows server 2003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we have two recovery models.

- Simple Recovery Model
- Full / Bulk Logged Recovery Model

To my experience in this scenerio, most SQL Servers there is no backup of the transaction log. Full backups or differential backups are common practice, but transaction log backups are really seldom. So the transaction log file grows forever (until the disk is full). In this case the recovery model should be set to "simple". Don't forget to modify the system databases "model" and "tempdb", too.

A backup of the database "tempdb" makes no sense, so the recovery model of this db should always be "simple".

Process:
What i do on my database.

Right Click on properties -> Option ->  Set Recovery Model: Simple.
Then, right click -> Tasks -> Shrink -> Files.

Just thats it will make space.

But for better practise we have to set recovery model: Full, in it log files not grow more and more we have to backup the log files. And to understand this scenario better I suggest you see these free videos.

[• SQL Server Backups Demystified](http://www.sqlservervideos.com/player/backups-demystified/)
[• SQL Server Logging Essentials](http://www.sqlservervideos.com/player/logging-essentials/)